# What is the best control to display two or more results one or more data tables?

Tags: c#

I have a function which matches the search criteria and return a data table. Everything works fine if it jsut returns one data table. I just use the values to fill up the text boxes. What control should I use to store when I have multiple results? Like if the user searches with a first name foo, it results 2 people will the that name. I want to make a form where the user can select one of these customers. What control do I need to use two display multiple results? This is a windows forms application.

```
dt DataTable = new DataTable

st = foo.GetPerson()
```

st might be one or two data tables. So How do I display the datatable row item in a seperate form and the user selects which one and I can show the details on a different form.

Comment: Why not just simply a DataGridView?

Comment: @SainathKrishnan I just added code.

Comment: @shriop Could I give the data source for DataGridView be a data table?

Comment: Yep. That's what it's made for. It works best if you create a typed DataTable, and use all the visual designers instead of creating an untyped DataTable on the fly like you are, but it will work if you just set the DataSource property to your dt variable.

Comment: @shriop How would I bind the data to it?

Comment: I don't understand where you're stuck. Try reading this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.90).aspx .

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using datagrid with two or three column which will differentiate among others and put a radio button in first column to select which row you want to select .For example you can see [this railway site](http://www.indianrail.gov.in) and search train between any two station, then you may get the idea what I am talking about.

For interaction between two form you can use this trick,
let say you have two form parent and child forms
modify constructor of child form like

```
public child(parent parentref)
```

and pass the reference of parent form, from parent while calling child like this

```
child childobj=new child(this)
```

using this parent reference from child you can access all the public control of parent
You can do this technique both ways.
I hope this helps